# What does a member and collection route mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Reading this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

What does it mean to add a 'member route'?

or do add a route to the collection?

What is a member and a collection when talking about routes?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

They're both ways to add additional actions to a resource-based route in Rails.

> - A member route requires an ID, because it acts on a member.
> - A collection route doesn't require an ID because it acts on a    collection of objects.

I like to think of them in terms of RESTful URLs. Consider the basics for a resource/model `Foo`

```
GET    /foo            # FooController#index
GET    /foo/:id        # FooController#show
GET    /foo/new        # FooController#new
POST   /foo            # FooController#create
GET    /foo/:id/edit   # FooController#edit
PUT    /foo/:id        # FooController#update
DELETE /foo/:id        # FooController#destroy
```

Notice how:

- Some routes have :id placeholders for Foo.id, and so refer to a *specific* Foo
- Some routes have no :id, and thus refer to *all* Foos (and/or no specific foo, as in #new and #create)
- Some routes (index/create, show/update/destroy) have the same URL, and use HTTP methods to differentiate between them
- Some routes (edit/show) are basically the same (method & URL prefix) except for a different suffix (including "no suffix") at the end.

Member routes and collection routes let you add additional routes/actions using the same techniques as I listed above.

A member route adds a custom action to a *specific instance* using the URL suffix and HTTP method you provide. So, if you had a member route declaration of `:member => { :bar => :get }`. you'd get an additional route of:

```
GET    /foo/:id/bar # FooController#bar
```

Note how it overloads `GET /foo/:id` in the same way that `edit' does. This is how you'd implement a "delete" action that provides a UI for the "destroy" action.

Similarly, a collection route adds an overload to the *collection* and/or a non-specific instance (it's up to you to decide exactly what it implies). So, if you declared `:collection => { :baz => :get }`, you'd get an additional route:

```
GET    /foo/baz        # FooController#baz
```

...in very much the same way as `new`.

You can also customize the HTTP method.

For example, I just recently had a project where I needed a "reply" action on a `Comment`. It's basically the same idea as `Comment#create` (which uses POST), except that it's in reference to a specific parent `Comment`. So, I created a member route: `:member => { :reply => :post }`. This gave me:

```
POST   /comment/:id/reply   # CommentController#reply
```

This keeps the routes restful while still expanding upon the basic 7 actions.

Comment: I had to read it a few times (learning ROR and Ruby), but this answer is very clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The built in member routes are `show`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy`, since they handle an individual record. `index` would be a collection route as it returns a collection of records.

So it really depends if you want to do something with a single record (member) or multiple records (collection).

The url helpers reflect singular (member) and plural (collection). For example:

This is a member:

```
person_path(@person)
```

This is a collection:

```
people_path()
```

If you define a custom collection path, it could look like this in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :people do
  member do
    put :make_manager
  end
  collection do
    get :show_managers
  end
end
```

To make somebody a manger:

```
make_manager_person_path(@person)
```

To list all managers:

```
show_managers_people_path()
```

I don't think that the route "cares" if you use it differently, but this is the Rails way. It will make your code easier to read and other coders will have it easier to understand and maintain your code.

Comment: what I don't get is, what do the routes care if its a member related route or a collection?

Comment: I updated my answer to give it more depth.